# an ErrorMessage in material-table

Tags: material-table

i'm trying to put an error message when i make a validation.
for example- when user try to update email, and he's email are not validate, i have the emailError 'email are not validate',
i wont this apear down the input field.
there is someone that can help me to fix that?
thanks.

```
this.state = {
    columns: [
        { title: 'Name', field: 'fullName', },
        { title: 'Permission groups', field: 'permissionGroups' },
        { title: 'Email', field: 'email' }
    ],
    formErrors: { emailError: '', fullNameError: '', permissionGroupsError: '' }
```

//

```
<MaterialTable

    icons={tableIcons}
    columns={this.state.columns}
    data={this.props.rows}
    editable={{
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.checkValidation()){

                resolve();
            }                                
            reject();
            }, 600);
        }),
        onRowAdd: newData =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.checkValidation()) {

                resolve();
            }
            reject();
            }, 600);
        }),
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a little bit tricky. You need to override the `editComponent` to show the error messages. For that, you could block the onChange function passed to `editComponent` and use hooks to keep a local state. The local state handles the new input and the validation. THe content is only passed back to the table, if the validation succeed.

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-selection-different-data-from-table-jtpyd) for you to check out.

Comment: This will be possible with the soon to be available feature to validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply validate the email using the **validate** prop in material table.

```
 columns: [
    { 
       title: 'Email', 
       field: 'email',
       validate : rowData => { 
        const EMAIL_REGEX = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        if(!EMAIL_REGEX.test(rowData.email)){
           return{isValid:false,helperText:'Invalid Email'}
        }else{
           return true
        }
       }
     }
],
```